# Any way to save current network config into /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, ip

I've configured my network using several `ip` commands, got all the interfaces up, everything works fine and I'm happy. But I want to export this config into a file (and later use that file as `/etc/network/interfaces`)

How do I do it?

Comment: @user535733 how would you do this with netplan?

Comment: @user535733 Oh... too bad I'm still on 16.4 LTS. Is there a way for an earlier version?

Comment: Please edit your question to include important information (your version of Ubuntu). Please don't bury important information in comments, which are intended to help you refine and improve the Question.